# Problems with the $ (dollar sign) inside RJournal template code chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've been trying to use the dollar sign ($) within some code chunks of a .Rmd (rmarkdown) file that uses the RJournal template. But, whenever the $ is inside a string, as in `plot(series, ylab = "US$")`, I cannot compile the text. I'm surprised to find out people haven't been asking around about this. Is the solution that obvious? I've tried everything I could, including escaping the $ with '\' (backlash). What should I do?

PS. It only happens if I use the RJournal template and I'm using RStudio Version 0.99.896.

Comment: This is a known bug. See the relevant github [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/49) and suggested work around.

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. I propose to close this as a duplicate of the other question, that is more detailed.

Comment: @scoa please read the other question thoroughly. It's a different problem and I even explain why (it happens even when I don't use the dollar sign and I DO get an output, which is not the case here). I agree that the title might be misleading, though

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I explained why it isn't a duplicate in the comment above